# Choosing an equivalent relay

Tags: relay

I have to replace a faulty SPDT [895-1C-C](http://www.songchuan.ru/files/895.pdf) relay so now I'm looking to buy the product. The problem is that this model it's not the most popular in the world so I thought that I might use something equivalent instead.

I wrote a list with few properties that I consider are important when searching the equivalent relay:

- to have the same PCB terminal type (eg. 1C => SPDT)
- to support the same resistive load (eg: NC=10A/14VDC, NO=20A/14VDC)
- to support the same coil voltage
- max carry current per unit of time

Other props that I regard as optional are insulation type, shock resistance of life expectancy.

Since the relay would be soldered on a PCB its size should be also considered, for obvious reasons.

Btw: on the PCB board there are 4 such identical relays. I want to replace only one. This should be also taken into account.

What do you think that is most important when searching for such equivalents (specifically for relay equivalents) ?

Comment: For instance I found a SRA-12VDC-CL which looks very close to the faulty 895 one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track...

- Relay Type (Form A, Form B, Form C)
- Footprint
- Coil voltage
- Switching voltage Max (greater than or equal to 895-1C-C)
- Switching current max (greater than or equal to 895-1C-C)

Once you have these parameters, a quick parameterized search on your favorite Vendor's website should give you any/all matching parts.

Keep in mind you really only need to match the switching voltage/current for your specific application in this case. For instance, if you are switching a motor, the motor switching ratings are important. Otherwise you can disregard them.

Comment: Thx Jim, I really appreciate it.